# WebStorm Node.js debug with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, webstorm, nodemon

I'm trying to debug a Node.js script with WebStorm 2019.3 and Docker as a remote Node interpreter. So far I can start the script, debug it, but any changes done on local do not trigger a nodemon restart of the script inside the Docker container (files inside the container ARE actually changing, I've checked).

Any ideas? I'll attach the WebStorm run config.

I think there is something wrong about the way that I'm using nodemon when starting the script, but I have no idea how to fix it for WebStorm config.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need to enable `legacyWatch`.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/#application-isnt-restarting):

> In some networked environments (such as a container running nodemon reading across a mounted drive), you will need to use the `legacyWatch: true` which enables Chokidar's polling.

> Via the CLI, use either --legacy-watch or -L for short: `nodemon -L`